# Is there a way to get all symbols for an entire platform for a closed-network?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I need to debug a kernel dump in a closed-network for W2K8 R2.  I tried to download the "Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2" symbols using the "Windows 7 Service Pack 1 x64 retail symbols, all languages" package from
[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

I burn it, copy it over, and load the symbols, and WinDbg claims it's the wrong PDB for `ntkrnlmp.pdb`.  So this is fine except I don't want to keep doing this to try and find the correct package to download.

I started looking into this question and find lots of articles talking about ways to have `symchk` recursively look at the local directories for Windows or System32 to auto-download the PDBs for those files.

But I need to be able to download all PDBs for a different OS than what's searching the web: Windows 2008 R2, not Win7.

Is there a way to download all possible symbols for Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 7 so they can be copied/burned and ultimately used on a closed network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### All symbols for the dump

A way which I used was to download all symbols needed by the dump. This can be done as follows:

1. Create a list of symbols on the restricted machine
2. Copy the list to a machine with Internet connection
3. Download all symbols on the machine with Internet connection
4. Copy the symbols back to the restricted machine

That way you needn't copy any sensitive information (like the dump) from the restricted machine.

The tool to achieve this is `symchk` which comes with WinDbg. The following commands should work:

1. `symchk /id <dumpfile>.dmp /om symbols.lst`
2. *whatever you like*
3. `symchk /im symbols.lst /s srv*X:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols /od`
4. *whatever you like* (copy the symbols from X:\symbols)

Parameters are:

- `/id` input is a dump file
- `/om` output is a manifest file
- `/im` input is a manifest file
- `/s` symbol server
- `/od` output verbose to see problems

### All symbols of Windows

The same approach can be used to download all symbols for your OS. The command for step 4 is then

```
symchk /r /if %windir% /om symbols.lst
```

Where the parameters are:

- `/r` recursively
- `/if` input from file (or directory, if recursively)

Comment: Why symchk works very slowly on machine without internet? Any advice on speeding up the process?

Comment: @vlad2135: it's a command to download things from the Internet. Why run the command on a machine without Internet access?

Comment: @vlad2135: ah, ok. I see. I assume the PC is connected to a local network, so it has a physical connection. Local network traffic is fine, however, Internet access is blocked. In such a case, it may help to physically disconnect the PC from the network. This will make requests fail immediately instead of waiting for a timeout.